# The distance function is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $S\subset\Bbb R$ not empty, define $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=
\inf\{|x-s| ;s\in S\}$

then, prove that  $|f(x)-f(y)|\le|x-y| $ for any $x,y \in \Bbb R$

Comment: Have you tried the case where $S$ consists of a single point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$|x - s| \le |x - y| + |y - s|$ for every $s \in S$.
Hence $f(x) \le |x - y| + f(y)$.

Similarly $f(y) \le |x - y| + f(x)$.

Hence $|f(x) - f(y)| \le |x - y|$.

Comment: Indeed, the distance function on any metric space is continuous, by the same proof that you have given.

Comment: How do you know that the s will be the same s for both x and y? Isnt it possible the infcould involve different s for x and y?

Comment: @RichardKYu: They are not necessarily the same. However, for any $s\in S$,$$\begin{align}f(x)&\le|x-s|\tag{1a}\\&\le|x-y|+|y-s|\tag{1b}\\&=|x-y|+f(y)+(|y-s|-f(y))\tag{1c}\end{align}$$ For all $s\in S$, $|y-s|-f(y)\ge0$; however, we can choose an $s\in S$ so that $|y-s|-f(y)$ is as small as we wish. Thus, $$f(x)\le|x-y|+f(y)\tag2 $$