# For any subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$, the distance function $d_s(x) = d(x,S)$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $S \subset \mathbb R$ be any set, and define for any $x \in \mathbb R$ the distance between $x$ and the set $S$ by $d(x,S) = \inf\{|x-s| : s \in S\}$.

1. Prove that the function $d_s: \mathbb R \to [0,+\infty)$ given by $d_s(x) = d(x,S)$, is Lipschitz continuous.
2. Prove that if $S$ is compact then for every $x$ in $\mathbb R$, there is $s$ in $S$ such that
   $|x-s| = d(x,S).$

Comment: This question is about to receive a serious amount of down votes and even may be closed. You must include some work you've tried and learn to use latex formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the help, first time using this website but i wouldn't have posted if i knew where to start. I understand the definition of lipschitz however i guess I'm stuck understanding the initial statement. I would have loved to use latex on this website but i did not see where it would let me. I was typing as i was using latex but it did not recognize any of the commands.

Comment: Okay, I will edit the question and give you some hints.

Comment: Thank you, i appreciate it.

Comment: For #1, consider the following slightly simpler situation to get the main idea. You fix a point $x$ and let's assume that the the **minimum** distance to $S$ exists and is achieved by $s.$ Now wiggle $x$ around a bit by an amount $\epsilon.$ Then the distance of the wiggled $x$'s from $S$ can't be more than $\epsilon$ since that's how far the wiggled $x$'s will be from $s$ (indeed, there might be elements in $S$ that are closer to the wiggled $x$'s than $s$ is).

Comment: Regarding my too hastily written comment, the distance of the wiggled $x$'s to $S$ can't **differ** from the distance of $x$ to $S$ by more than $\epsilon$ since . . .

Comment: The first question is answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192596/the-distance-function-is-continuous?rq=1)

Comment: @6005 how does that question relate to the Lipschitz continuous definition since if a function is continuous it is not necessarily Lipschitz continuous

Comment: @Tilly If you read the question it says to prove that $|f(x) - f(y)| \le |x - y|$.

Comment: Ahh yea i missed that! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

For the first part, observe that $d(x,s)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,s)$ and $d(y,s)\leq d(x,y)+d(x,s)$.

For the second part, note that for fixed $x,\ $ $f(s)=\vert x-s\vert $ is continuous on the compact set $S$.

Comment: For the first part, i guess i don't see how you came up with that $d(x,s)$ $\ge$ $d(x,y) + d(y,s). $The definition that i have includes  K being the constant  such that K $\ge$ 0$  @Chilango

Comment: I think you have the inequality reversed. Anyway, in my answer, it's just the triangle inequality where $d$ is absolute value, and $s$ is any element of $S$. You will use this before passing to the infimum.

Comment: Okay i understand the first part using the triangle ineq. But what do you mean before passing the infimum, since we are proving that $d_s$ :$R$ $\to [o,+inf)$, $d_s$(x)= d(x,S) is L.C?  @chilango